# Adding image to rtf doc being resized

Tags: c#, rtf, migradoc

We're using migradoc api to create an rtf document.. intermittently when we add an image it;s being resized and coming out absolutely tiny.

Code sample as follows:

```
MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Shapes.Image image = section.AddImage(imagePath);
image.WrapFormat.Style = MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Shapes.WrapStyle.Through;
```

If I set LockAspectRatio to true and set a width it does stop is from rendering very small but ideally would like to be able to set a MaxWidth.

Has anyone experiences similar issue?

Comment: Have you checked the DPI of the image in addition to its pixel size?

Comment: @TaW The original image with the problem has 300 dpi x 300 dpi and 100px x 100px.

Strange - when I copy the image and re-save it in Paint (the most advanced image tool) it doesn't come out tiny this time. But when I view the file properties it doesn't show the DPI on the new file.

Comment: PDF is respecting DPIs. So 100px with 300dpi will result in 1/3 of an inch. Calculate the size you want and set the dpi accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a choice of either changing the image itself by storing a different DPI value in it.

The .Net command to do so with a Bitmap bmp is:

```
bmp.SetResolution(newHRes , newVRes);
```

This **should** not involve reencoding, but I'm not sure.

However you also can simply set the desired DPI value in the Migradoc Image by using its `Image.Resolution Property`, which

> Gets or sets a user defined resolution for the image in dots per inch.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with  it at all but I found this code that might help you :

```
image.RelativeVertical = RelativeVertical.Page;
image.RelativeHorizontal = RelativeHorizontal.Page;
```

Comment: Thanks.. will take a look at that also.